# flexibility of android user interface using native java code

Tags: android, hybrid-mobile-app

I would like to create the following interface in Android:

[image]

However it appears to me that if I code in Java the opportunities
for achieving this look exactly as it appears here are fairly limited.
Am I right or wrong? Should I use an HTML hybrid app instead?

Thanks.

Comment: There's no question here, try to implement your UI and find out for yourself.  You'll learn more that way.

Comment: There's nothing in here that seems particularly difficult to do in the Android UI framework. That being said, this isn't a suitable question structure for StackOverflow. If you try implementing this, and you run into specific problems, feel free to post new questions showing what you have tried and how it is failing to meet your objectives.

Comment: Well, I was not sure about how to implement the rounded corners and the logo inside the text box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was not sure about how to implement the rounded corners and the logo inside the text box

The rounded corners would be a custom background to the container holding onto those widgets, either [a `ShapeDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#shape-drawable), or [a nine-patch PNG file](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch).

The logo inside the `EditText` widget would be [via `android:drawableRight`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3adrawableRight).